# Returning Laravel blade syntax in php string

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel, in my controller I have a function that returns a built up String:

```
public function getAddEditRemoveColumnData()
    {
        $projects = Project::select(['id', 'name', 'cost', 'created_at']);

        return Datatables::of($projects)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($project) {
                return '<div class="btn-group">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/projects/' . $project->id . '/edit">Edit</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a>{!! Form::open(array("url" => "projects/" . $project->id, "class" => "", "id" => "delete-form")) !!}
                                {!! Form::hidden("_method", "DELETE") !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-link delete-action" style="color:inherit; text-decoration: none;">Delete</button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>';
            })
            ->make(true);
    }
```

The blade syntax that creates the form is not being evaluated as it is being treated as a string literal. Is there any way I can get around this and get the blade syntax `{{ }}` to be interpreted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your html/blade in a template so you can use the `render()` function of the `View` Facade/class, as example:

```
 $string = view('your_template_file')->render();
```

`render()` returns the compiled template as a string, so you can try to do something like that:

```
public function getAddEditRemoveColumnData()
{
    $projects = Project::select(['id', 'name', 'cost', 'created_at']);

     return Datatables::of($projects)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($project) {
            return view('your_template_file', compact('project'))->render();
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for `\Blade::compileString()`. This function takes your blade string and returns the compiled php code.

So you have to use `eval` afterwards to interpret the php code.

```
function compile($string, $args) {
    $code = \Blade::compileString($string);
    ob_start();
    extract($args);
    eval('?>' . $code);
    return ob_end_clean();
}
```